# Pass complex object to component page

Tags: c#, .net, blazor, blazor-webassembly

I have a razor component called projects that has a list of projects with different properties.

I have them listed in a table with something like this:

```
<table>
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Project Number</th>
        <th>Project Name</th>
        <th>Status</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    @foreach (var p in projects)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>@p.ProjectId</td>
            <td>@p.Name</td>
            <td>@p.ProjectStatus</td>
        </tr>
    }
    </tbody>
</table>
```

now, I want that when the user clicks on the "projectId" it navigates to another page that will have the detailed information for this particular project, which I understand is done like this:

```
<button @onclick="() => ButtonHandler(p.ProjectId)">@p.ProjectId</button>

@code
{

    private void ButtonHandler(int projectId)
    {

        Project = projects.First(x => x.ProjectId == projectId);
        navigationManager.NavigateTo($"/projectdetail/{projectId}");

    }
}
```

this projectId I'm passing is because I want to filter the project list into a single object "Project" that I want to pass to my "projectDetail" component.

in my projectDetail.razor I have the following:

```
@page "/projectdetail/{ProjectId:int}"

@code {

    [Parameter]
    public Project Project { get; set; } = null!;
}
```

however this doesn't seem to work, the Project property is null when I reach to it.

Can I get some help about how to properly pass the object from "ProjectList" to "ProjectDetail"?

I have tried with the component passing as well by doing

```
<td>@project.ProjectId <ProjectDetail Project="Project"></ProjectDetail></td>
```

but it seems that as this being inside the foreach loop is doing it every time instead of just the one I need when the users clicks on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the point of view of UI design, it's better to have the list of projects in a tabular element at the top of the page, and the project detail below it. This allows you to view the project's detail instantly, as you select a project in the list of project. This means that your project detail is no longer a routable component, and it is embedded within the projects component. And now, you can query
`Project = projects.First(x => x.ProjectId == projectId);`, in the ButtonHandler method, the projects list in order to get the selected project, and pass it as a parameter to the embedded component.

Note that the above suggested design is also more efficient and fast, as Blazor does not destroy the elements in the Detail component, and recreate them a new. It uses the same objects to dispaly the new data.

But if you insist on creating a dedicted page for the project's detail, you should pass only the `ProjectId` to the Detail component:

```
@page "/projectdetail/{ProjectId:int}"
@inject ProjectsService projectsService

@code {
    [Parameter]
    public int ProjectId { get; set; }

    private Project project;

    protected override void OnInitialized()
    {
        project = ProjectsService.GetProjectById(ProjectId);
    }
}
```

Note: Your ProjectsService should implement the state pattern. There shouldn't be any issue of querying the database again and again. Its life time should span the duration of the app. Thus when you call the `GetProjectById` method, it accesses the collection of projects stored in a variable defined in the service, and returns the selected project. No database call. See [here how it is done](https://github.com/aspnet/samples/blob/main/samples/aspnetcore/blazor/FlightFinder/FlightFinder.Client/Services/AppState.cs)

Comment: thank you, this does solve the issue, however I'm interested in what you posted as the "better design" how would be the tabular element? to hide the project list and show the project detail component when clicked?   is there an example I could check on this please? thank you so much for your time

Comment: I'm open to handle it without the redirection if this means that can cleanly achieve the look of "seeing the project list" -> clicking on a project and the "seeing the project details" whilst hiding the project list, (and having a way to get back to the project list)

Comment: You can "hide" the list of projects by defining a boolean variable which you can set to false in the ButtonHandler method, and re-display it by setting it to true in a button's click method placed at the bottom of the project detail component. But, alas, this is a bad idea, to my mid, and you'd better use re-direction instead.

Answer (score 2):

You are passing a `ProjectId` route parameter to the `ProjectDetail.razor` page which you should use to fetch the `Project`:

```
@page "/projectdetail/{ProjectId:int}"

@code {
    [Parameter]
    public int ProjectId { get; set; }

    private Project project;

    protected override void OnInitialized()
    {
        project = ProjectService.GetProjectById(ProjectId);
    }
}
```

**Edit:**

Only way to pass the entire `Project` object to the `ProjectDetails` page would be to serialize it to JSON string and pass it using a string route parameter.

**ProjectDetails.razor:**

```
@page "/productdetails/{ProjectJson}"
@using System.Text.Json

@code {
    [Parameter]
    public string ProjectJson { get; set; }

    private Project project { get; set; }

    protected override void OnInitialized()
    {
        project = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<Project>(ProjectJson);
    }
}
```

**ProjectList.razor:**

```
<button @onclick="() => ButtonHandler(p.ProjectId)">@p.ProjectId</button>

@code {
    private void ButtonHandler(int projectId)
    {
        Project = projects.First(x => x.ProjectId == projectId);
        navigationManager.NavigateTo($"projectdetail/{JsonSerializer.Serialize(Project)}");
    }
}
```

Comment: I understand this way, however in this case I will have to do another call to the database to get the project information that I already had, is there a way that I can pass the entire project on the call so I don't have to go to the database again?

Comment: @Baldie47 Managing objects like that should not be the responsibility of the UI. When you really want to avoid the (refreshing) call to the Db then build some caching into the ProjectService.